Multigrid: difference between Rediscretization and Galerkin coarsening in presence of jumping coefficients
I read/heard (e.g. Klaus Stüben: "Introduction to algebraic Multigrid") that in the presence of jumping coefficients, Galerkin coarsening can fix Multigrid convergence when Rediscretization Multigrid diverges. This is supposedly because Galerkin coarsening produces a more "faithful representation" of the fine grid operator on the coarse grid than Rediscretization does (with jumping coefficients). I am guessing that when rediscretizing with a jump, the jump might not be resolved/placed accurately to the fine grid.
Can anyone pinpoint what's the reason for Rediscretization failing in such cases?
Many thanks in advance.
